# Regex matching more than {7}

Tags: c#, regex

I generally extract Dell service tags from a huge list and I have a a bit of code that is supposed to extract the 7 Alpha-Numeric tags, but if there is extra text int the document, it will sometimes extract that extra text.

My Pattern:

```
Regex rServTag_Pattern = new Regex(@".*(?=.{7})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*");
var mTag = rServTag_Pattern.Match(Clipboard.GetText());
```

For the most part it really works, but after some time it can get annoying and extract more than what is needed. How can I make sure it extracts only the 7Alpha-Numeric string?

Example service tags: 7DJHT90, LK2JHN4, and so on (these are not actual service tags.

Comment: Can you post some sample input that contains the service tags?  Giving us a bit of extra text to work with will help us to capture the correct substrings and avoid the unwanted bits.  Are the service tags always only CAPS and digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
var rServTag = new Regex(@"(?=([a-zA-Z]+\d[a-zA-Z\d]+|\d+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+))[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}");
```

If you need to avoid extracting 7 letter+digit combinations from inside text, you can add word boundaries:

```
var rServTag = new Regex(@"\b(?=([a-zA-Z]+\d[a-zA-Z\d]+|\d+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+))[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}\b");
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, it matches words as well and not just alpha-numeric characters alone.

http://regexr.com/3g318

Comment: Letters are alphanumeric characters. I suppose you mean it must have both letters and numbers.

Comment: @herboren Okay, updated my RE to something complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use wordboundaries to isolate 7 characters.

```
Regex rServTag_Pattern = new Regex(@".*\b[A-Z\d]{7}\b.*");
```

This assumes only capitals and digits in the service tag (based on OP's sample input)

Comment: @herboren I am not a c# coder.  If my answer doesn't work, I'd prefer to delete it from this page.  Can you tell me if it works for your case?

Answer (score 0):

I would split your problem into two steps:

- Split the input by a delimiter
- Process each split string

---

In your case, I would split `Clipboard.GetText()` by all non-alphnumeric characters:

```
string[] splitArray = Regex.Split(Clipboard.GetText(), @"[^a-zA-Z\d]+");
foreach (string s in splitArray)
{
    // process s
}
```

Then for each split string `s`, apply a regex that only matches strings which have at least one letter `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`, at least one digit `(?=.*\d)`, and is exactly 7 characters long `^[a-zA-Z\d]{7}$`:

```
new Regex(@"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{7}$");
```

Example:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{7}$");
string[] splitArray = Regex.Split(Clipboard.GetText(), @"[^a-zA-Z\d]+");
foreach (string s in splitArray)
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(s))
    {
        // s is a valid service tag
    }
}
```

Given the input `"123ABCD, ABCDEFG... ABCD123, 123AAAAAAAA"`, `splitArray` will equal `["123ABCD", "ABCDEFG", "ABCD123", "123AAAAAAAA"]`.

`regex.IsMatch(s)` will return true for `s` `"123ABCD"` and `"ABCD123"`.